# Allocate memory for big .txt file in C

Tags: c, memory, malloc, dynamic-memory-allocation, calloc

I need to allocate memory using malloc or calloc, for a large file that looks like this:

```
2357 VKLYKK
7947 1WTFWZ
3102 F2IXK3
2963 EXMW55
2865 50CJES
2510 8PC1AI
```

There are around 10K of lines in that .txt file. How can I allocate the required memory?

What is the program supposed to do? The program has to read the whole `.txt` file. Sort it by the first number and send output to `out.txt`. But since the the input of the file is huge it won't let me.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#pragma warning(disable : 4996)

typedef struct {
    int number;
    char order[10];
} Data;

int sorting(const void *a, const void *b)
{
    Data *dataA = (Data *)a;
    Data *dataB = (Data *)b;

    // return (dataA->number - dataB->number);  // Ascending order
    return (dataB->number - dataA->number);  // Descending order
}

int main()
{
    FILE *fp;
    FILE *f = fopen("out.txt", "w");
    Data data[20];
    char *line[150]
    int i = 0;
    char file_name[10] = "";

    printf("enter file name: ");
    scanf("%s", &file_name);
    fp = fopen(file_name, "r");
    if (fp == NULL)
    {
        printf("\n%s\" File not found!", file_name);
        exit(1);
    }
    while (1)
    {
        if (fgets(line, 150, fp) == NULL)
            break;

        char *pch;
        pch = strtok(line, " ");
        data[i].number = atoi(pch);     
        pch = strtok(NULL, " ");
        strcpy(data[i].order, pch);
        i++;     
    }
    printf("#################\n");
    printf("number\torder\n"); 
    for (int k = 0; k < 10; k++)
    {
        printf("%d\t%s", data[k].number, data[k].order);
    }

    qsort(data, 10, sizeof(Data), sorting);

    printf("\n#################\n");
    printf("number\torder\n"); 
    for (int k = 0; k < 10; k++)
    {
        printf("%d\t%s", data[k].number, data[k].order);
        fprintf(f, "%d\t%s", data[k].number, data[k].order);
    }
    fclose(fp);
    fclose(f);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Aside on flow logic: `while (1) { if (fgets(line, 150, fp) == NULL) break; ...` is more idiomatic as `while (fgets(line, sizeof line, fp) != NULL)`

Comment: What is it about the allocation that you need help with? Is it knowing how much to allocate? If so, common strategies are to use `fseek/ftell` to get the file size or use an initial `malloc` size followed by `realloc` if needed to grow the size.

Comment: `dataB->cislo` does not compile.

Comment: Aside #2: `pch = strtok(NULL, " ");` should be `pch = strtok(NULL, " \n");` because `fgets` keeps the newline in the input string.

Comment: "10K of lines in that .txt" it too large for `Data data[20];`

Comment: I tried to allocate data but it is not working, it always has problem with this line ```(fgets(line, 150, fp) == NULL) break;```

Comment: Do *not* read the entire file into one chunk of memory.  There's no point.  Since the goal is to sort the file by lines, it makes more sense to use a reasonable data structure.  (ie, allocate space for one line and insert the line into a tree)

Comment: 10k lines means the file is about 100k.  Not *huge* by any modern standard.  Practically tiny by many measures.

Comment: "File not found" is a terrible error message to give if the file exists but the user does not have permission to read it.  Use `fp = fopen(file_name, "r"); if (fp == NULL){perror(file_name); exit(1); }`.  This gives a reason for the failure, and it writes the error message to stderr.  Error messages belong on stderr.

Answer (score 2):

If your file contains 10,000 lines or so, your `while` loop will quickly overrun your `data` array (which you declared with only 20 elements). If the number of lines is not known in advance, the best way to do this is with a growing array. Start by initialing `data` (and new `dataSize` and `dataCount` variables) as follows:

```
int dataSize = 0;
int dataCount = 0;
Data *data = NULL;
```

Then as you use up the space in the array, when it reaches `dataSize` entries you will have to grow your array. Something like this:

```
while (1) {
    if (dataCount >= dataSize) {
        Data *new;
        dataSize += 1000;
        new = realloc(data,dataSize * sizeof *data);
        if (new == NULL) {
            perror("realloc");
            free(data);
            return 2;
        }
        data = new;
    }     
    int cnt = fscanf(fp,"%d %9s", &data[dataCount].number, data[dataCount].order);
    if (cnt == EOF)
        break;
    if (cnt != 2) {
        printf("Error reading data\n");
        return 1;
    }
    dataCount++;
}
```

When the while loop finishes (if there were no errors), the `data` array will contain all of the data, and `dataCount` will be the total number of data items found.

Note that I used `fscanf` instead of `fgets`, as this eliminates the need for intermediate step like calls to `atoi` and `strcpy`. I also put in some simple error checking. I chose 1000 as the growth increment, though you can change that. But too small and it fragments the heap more rapidly, and too big requires larger amounts of memory too quickly.

Comment: Meen its not working for me idk why :/

Comment: "Meen"? And what do you mean by "not working"? Error message? Unexpected behavior?

Comment: It is showing errors with "new".

Comment: @Astaroth What is the error message?

Answer (score 1):

this line

```
char* line[150];
```

creates an array of 150 char pointers, this is not what you want if you are reading one line like this

```
if (fgets(line, 150, fp) == NULL) break;
```

I suspect you wanted one line of 150 chars

so do

```
 char line[150];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `qsort` to sort the array of lines, but that may not be the best approach.  It may be more effective to insert the lines into a data structure that can be easily traversed in order.  Although this simple minded solution is very much less than ideal, here's a simple-minded example of inserting into a tree.  This sorts the lines lexicographically; modifying it to sort numerically based on the line is a good exercise.

```
/* Build an (unbalanced) binary search tree of lines in input. */

#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

static void * xrealloc(void *buf, size_t num, size_t siz, void *end);
FILE * xfopen(const char *path, const char *mode);

struct entry {
    const char *line;
    struct entry *node[2];
};

static struct entry *
new_node(const char *line)
{
    struct entry *e = calloc(1, sizeof *e);
    if( e == NULL ){
        perror("calloc");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    e->line = line;
    return e;
}

/*
 * Note that this tree needs to be rebalanced.  In a real
 * project, we would use existing libraries.
 */
static struct entry *
lookup(struct entry **lines, const char *line)
{
    struct entry *t = *lines;
    if( t ){
        int cmp = strcmp(line, t->line);
        return lookup(&t->node[cmp > 0], line);
    } else {
        return *lines = new_node(line);
    }
}

/* In-order descent of the tree, printing one line per entry */
static void
print_table(const struct entry *t)
{
    if( t ){
        print_table(t->node[0]);
        printf("%s", t->line);
        print_table(t->node[1]);
    }
}

static void *
xrealloc(void *buf, size_t num, size_t siz, void *endvp)
{
    char **endp = endvp;
    ptrdiff_t offset = endp && *endp ? *endp - (char *)buf : 0;
    buf = realloc(buf, num * siz);
    if( buf == NULL ){
        perror("realloc");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    if( endp != NULL ){
        *endp = buf + offset;
    }
    return buf;
}

int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    FILE *ifp = argc > 1 ? xfopen(argv[1], "r") : stdin;
    struct entry *lines = NULL;
    char *line = NULL;
    size_t cap = 0;
    while( getline(&line, &cap, ifp) > 0 ){
        (void) lookup(&lines, line);
        line = NULL;
    }
    print_table(lines);
}

FILE *
xfopen(const char *path, const char *mode)
{
    FILE *fp = path[0] != '-' || path[1] != '\0' ? fopen(path, mode) :
        *mode == 'r' ? stdin : stdout;
    if( fp == NULL ){
        perror(path);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    return fp;
}
```